# Forcefully Flash Light off during capturing image in android

Tags: android, camera, flashlight

I want to disable flash light during capturing image, i am using below code to open camera.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);



 @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(requestCode== 1)
    Uri uri = data.getData();

    }
```

using this code i can start camera, but after that i want to forcefully disable flash light programatically, How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

Insert this after you start camera and *before* you click image.

```
Camera cam = Camera.open();     
Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
cam.setParameters(p);
```

**Note:** You have to use the camera class *android.hardware.Camera* for this code to work.

Comment: @Gautam have you code of android.hardware.Camera  class. Thanks

Comment: When you *start camera*, are you using your own app, or opening through an existing camera app?

Comment: Dont getting, i m new to camera,

Comment: Are you making your own app to take pictures?

Comment: yes, after taking picture i want image Uri and i want to store in SD card

Comment: Update your question with the code you are using to *take pictures*.

Comment: This isn't what I asked. I meant have you used      *camera.takePicture(null,null,null,new pictureCallBack());* or something like that to take pictures?